# libcurl - CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION - новая сессия?

Tags: c, curl, cookie

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я правильно понимаю, то опция *CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION* - говорит либкурлу - не использовать куки, которые были ранее сохранены при предыдущих запросах.

Если так, то я делаю вот так:

1.Сначала делаю GET к сайту к примеру **ru.stackoverflow.com** вот с этими параметрами:

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, path_to_cookie);    

curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, path_to_cookie);
```

Смотрю Исходящие заголовки запроса, которые сформировал курл и вижу, что заголовка Cookie там нет, так как это самый первый запрос к сайту.

После этого запроса - закрываю соединения с серверо и курл записывает присланные куки с сервера в указанный файл - path_to_cookie.

Далее, я делаю второй запрос на этот же хост: ru.stackoverflow.com, но предварительно ставлю опцию CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION:

```
curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, path_to_cookie);    

curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, path_to_cookie); 

curl_easy_setopt(CURL_p, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);   //1 - значит не использовать куки.
```

И делаю опять запрос и смотрю Исходящие заголовки запроса. И вот там почему то теперь присутствуют куки от предыдущего запроса, хотя я ведь вызвал опцию *CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION* с параметром 1, что означает сделать запрос, как бы новой сессией.

И вот вопрос - *CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION* не работает или я не правильно ее использую ?

Как только дописал этот текст, подумал, а может те куки, которые курл получает с сайта не сессионные, а по времени и поэтому *CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION*  - не работает ?

Тогда, позвольте спросить, как понять - вот эти сохранённые курлом куки - это сессионные или по времени?

> Site1.ru  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   sid X62IRmGw2yi0h3+ILwKSAg==
>
> [www.Site2.ru](http://www.Site2.ru)  FALSE   /   TRUE    1670519902  cflastactivity  0
>
> [www.Site2.ru](http://www.Site2.ru)  FALSE   /   TRUE    1670519902  cflastvisit 1638980392
>
> #HttpOnly_.Site2.ru   TRUE    /   FALSE   1670516392  __ddg1  SQheHuSYs75LD5NttwsJ

Comment: @Kotomi, а Вы с какой целью это написали ? :)

Comment: @Kotomi, а, как Вы поняли, что я неправильно прочитал документацию ? То есть, какой вывод из Вашего первого сообщения - мне нужно сделать, чтобы он натолкнул меня на ответ на мой вопрос ?

Comment: Kotomi, так вот это и было мой "второй", те куки, которые CURL ранее сохранил в файл - это сесионые или по времени. Первый запрос же я закрыл. Я делаю второй запрос, ставлю не использовать куки - но CURL их ве равно подтягивает из файла. Подтягивает потому что в файле - нет сессионных куков ? Или сессионные куки CURL вообще в файл не сохраняет получается ?

Comment: Окей, тогда чтобы не разводить дискуссии, приложите нормальный код чтобы было понятно что вы там делаете.